# 2-Column Fixed Width Sidebar w/ Fluid Content Not Aligned Properly

Tags: css, layout, css-float, positioning, sidebar

I've been running into this problem for setting up 2-column layouts with a fixed sidebar floated to the right. I'm setting a margin on the content container so it will be fluid as you resize the browser window.

However the content section is actually "above" the sidebar, and so new content pushes the sidebar down the page. You can see a [live demo here](http://byjakewithlove.com/code/stack/2col/) which I setup for a basic layout.

The only way I know to fix this is by moving the sidebar above the content in my HTML markup. But this doesn't really feel like a fix, and honestly I would like my content to appear before the sidebar since that's how the document is structured. Is there any way to keep the floated sidebar aligned right at the top with the content area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Media Object http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/

demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/3729182

Since you have not provided the widths for the columns, I used my own in percentages. You can use Media Queries to clear the sidebar once it gets too thin.

Comment: I updated a [new dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/3730082) which better demonstrates my current problem. the right sidebar should be floating with a width of 250px. Notice if you cut/paste the right div above the left div it will float perfectly, but otherwise it falls underneath.

Comment: That's because you removed the float from the left column, which reverted it to its default property 'display: block', hence the right column clearing. The right column does not require 'float: right' since it is given 'overflow: hidden', more details are in the Media Object link I'd provided. It is well worth a read and will save you from repeating code.

But since you want to preserve source order, you can wrap the columns in a .container and with a little hack make a fluid grid: http://dabblet.com/gist/3730377.

Comment: What's happening here is that the .container has a 'padding-right' equal to the right column's width; the right column is given 'right: -100%' which pulls it to the padded area. It's not necessarily bad practice but we will have to do with such hacks until we get our hands on 'calc()' and 'flexbox'.

Comment: ah great thank you so much! Yes I do follow this method and I don't see anything wrong with using negative integers for positioning. It does seem to work perfectly so that's great! Again appreciate the help I'll play around some more with this new code

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't stop researching! :)